# Wire VMWare Player NIC to a VLAN in Ubuntu 8.04.3

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-esxi, centos, vlan

I've got VMWare Player 2.5.x installed on a Ubuntu 8.04.3 host running CentOS 5.3 running Cobbler. VMWare Player has two NICs (I actually took this image from an ESXi image, converted it to Player 2.x image via VMWare Standalone Converter).

I've also setup a vlan (vlan5) on the host with 10.0.0.x and I'd like Cobbler to use that VLAN to serve any incoming requests.

How do I wire up my VMWare to use the VLAN I've setup? Just one of the NICs.

What I'm trying to do is to offer a laptop with a VM that our sysadmins can go, plug it into a box (which does not connect to the interwebs) and install RHEL images via cobbler. So essentially, its a cross over cable from the network port on the lappy to the Dell server box. PXE boot in the dell box and install RHEL.

I have the cobbler working fine under VMWare ESXi but not so on the VMWare Player because of the VLAN issue - I think.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Run `vmware-config.pl` again and configure the network settings.  Specifically you want to setup your vlan interface to be available for bridging.